# VueJs Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

for the last 3 days I've been searching all over the net but couldn't find a solution to this issue. When I'm opening my page it gives this error:

```
ReferenceError: store is not defined
    at app.js:89294
    at iterator (app.js:71515)
    at step (app.js:71241)
    at runQueue (app.js:71249)
    at HTML5History.confirmTransition (app.js:71542)
    at HTML5History.transitionTo (app.js:71429)
    at VueRouter.init (app.js:72129)
    at Vue.beforeCreate (app.js:70598)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (app.js:76676)
    at callHook (app.js:79027)
```

I managed to track issue to my `router.js` file but couldn't fix the issue. I also tried to import my store file into router file but it returned `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

## Code

**Router.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import pageAbout from './components/About.vue';
import pageHome from './components/Home.vue';
import pageBooks from './components/Books.vue';
import pageChapters from './components/Chapters.vue';
import pageVerses from './components/Verses.vue';

import Dashboard from './components/admin/Dashboard.vue';
import Register from './components/auth/Register.vue';
import Login from './components/auth/Login.vue';

import passportclients from './components/passport/Clients.vue';
import passportauthorizedclients from './components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue';
import passportpersonalaccesstokens from './components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue';

import adminVerses from './components/admin/verses.vue';
import NotFoundComponent from './components/NotFoundComponent.vue';

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        {
            path: '*',
            name: '404',
            component: NotFoundComponent
        },
        // ADMIN ROUTES
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: Dashboard,
            meta: { requiresAuth: true },
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/verses',
                    name: 'adminVerses',
                    component: adminVerses,
                    meta: { requiresAuth: true }
                },
                {
                    path: '/passport-clients',
                    name: 'passport-clients',
                    component: passportclients,
                    meta: { requiresAuth: true }
                },
                {
                    path: '/passport-authorized-clients',
                    name: 'passport-authorized-clients',
                    component: passportauthorizedclients,
                    meta: { requiresAuth: true }
                },
                {
                    path: '/passport-personal-access-tokens',
                    name: 'passport-personal-access-tokens',
                    component: passportpersonalaccesstokens,
                    meta: { requiresAuth: true }
                }
            ]
        },

        // public routes
        {
            path: "/",
            name: 'home',
            component: pageHome
        },
        {
            path: "/about",
            name: 'about',
            component: pageAbout
        },
        {
            path: "/book/:slug",
            name: 'books',
            component: pageBooks
        },
        {
            path: "/book/:book_slug/:slug",
            name: 'chapters',
            component: pageChapters
        },
        {
            path: "/book/:testament_slug/:book_slug/:slug",
            name: 'verses',
            component: pageVerses
        },
        // auth
        {
            path: '/register',
            name: 'register',
            component: Register
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login
        }
    ]
});

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
        document.title = to.pageTitle || 'Bible';
    });
});


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    var requiresAuth = to.matched.some( record => record.meta.requiresAuth );
    // when route requires auth and there's no current user, reidrect to '/login'
    if(!store.getters.isLoggedIn){
      next({name: 'login'});
    // when we go to login route and are already logged in, we can skip this page
    // so we redirect to the homepage
    } else if (to.path == '/login' && store.getters.isLoggedIn){
      next({name: 'home'});
    // if none of the above matches, we have a normal navigation that should just go through
    // so we call `next()`
    } else {
      next(); // you called `next('/')` which redirected to the homepage over and over again.
    }
});

export default router;
```

**Store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    status: '',
    token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || '',
    type: localStorage.getItem('token_type') || '',
    user : {}
  },
  mutations: {
    auth_request(state){
        state.status = 'loading'
      },
      auth_success(state, type, token, user){
        state.status = 'success'
        state.token = token
        state.type = type
        state.user = user
      },
      auth_error(state){
        state.status = 'error'
      },
      logout(state){
        state.status = ''
        state.token = ''
        state.type = ''
      },
  },
  actions: {
    login({commit}, user){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          commit('auth_request')
          axios({url: '/api/auth/login', data: user, method: 'POST' })
          .then(resp => {
            console.log('login data', resp);
            const token = resp.data.token
            const type = resp.data.token_type
            const user = resp.data.user
            localStorage.setItem('token', token)
            localStorage.setItem('token_type', type)
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =  'Bearer ' + token
            commit('auth_success', token, type, user)
            resolve(resp)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            commit('auth_error')
            localStorage.removeItem('token')
            reject(err)
          })
        })
    },
    register({commit}, user){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          commit('auth_request')
          axios({url: 'api/auth/register', data: user, method: 'POST' })
          .then(resp => {
            console.log('register data', resp);
            const token = resp.data.access_token
            const type = resp.data.token_type
            const user = resp.data.user
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
            localStorage.setItem('token_type', type)
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =  'Bearer ' + token
            commit('auth_success', token, type, user)
            resolve(resp)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            commit('auth_error', err)
            localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
            reject(err)
          })
        })
      },
      logout({commit}){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({url: 'api/auth/logout', method: 'POST' })
          .then(resp => {
            commit('logout')
            localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
            localStorage.removeItem('token_type')
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
            resolve()
          })
          .catch(err => {
            commit('logout')
            localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
            localStorage.removeItem('token_type')
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
            reject(err)
          })
        })
      }
  },
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
    authStatus: state => state.status,
    LoggedUser: state => state.user,
  }
});
```

**App.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

import Darkmode from 'darkmode-js';
import App from "./components/App";

import 'es6-promise/auto';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import router from './router';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import 'es6-promise/auto';
import store from './store';


// Set Vue globally
window.Vue = Vue
// Set Vue router
Vue.router = router;
Vue.use(VueRouter);
// Set Vue authentication
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
Vue.use(Vuex);

const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
if (token) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
}

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    render: (h) => h(App)
});
```

**App.vue (main component)**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                user: ''
            }
        },
        computed : {
            isLoggedIn() {
                return this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn
            }
        },
        methods: {
            logout: function () {
                this.$store.dispatch('logout')
                .then(() => {
                    this.$router.push({name: 'home'})
                })
            }
        },
        created: function () {
            this.user = this.$store.state.user
        }
    }
</script>
```

## Question

**How to fix this error?**

## Update

Based on comment suggestion I have to import my store to `router.js` file and it returns **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error.

How to fix Maximum call stack size exceeded?

Comment: @JaromandaX the router is not a component. I don't think `this.$store` is defined on it.

Comment: @mafortis you should change the title. You know how to solve the `not defined` issue. Your real issue is the stack overflow.

Comment: @JaromandaX it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined`

Comment: @MarkMeyer the title is my error message :) what do you like me to change it to? :D

Comment: @mafortis my point is that using the `store` without importing is never going to work — you need to import the name to use it. That's why you are getting that error. Given that, the error you need to solve is the one you buried: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: ok i will edit my question, anyway have any idea for `Maximum call stack size exceeded`?

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, misread where the issue was - the code in the question (at first glance) looks like it's doing things correctly (one store is imported correctly) - of course, there is the usual promise constructor anti-pattern so, probably code that's infinitely recursive somewhere in there

Comment: it's too bad the error message doesnt' have a stack trace you can trace back to a particular line in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX unfortunately this is all i'm getting https://ibb.co/n6t7D0b

Comment: well, that's useful to know - read this https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded/1994 - since `if(!store.getters.isLoggedIn){` is true, you redirect to login, and `if(!store.getters.isLoggedIn){` is true, so you redirect to login, and `if(!store.getters.isLoggedIn){` is true, so you redirect to login... etc - try adding `&& to.path !== '/login'` to that if statement

Comment: @JaromandaX based on your provided link i 've changed my code like `} else if (to.path !== '/login' && store.getters.isLoggedIn) {` yet i get same result

Comment: because you didn't do what I suggested - the FIRST if needs to be such that you don't keep redirecting to login in an infinite loop - once an if statement is true, no `else` will even be considered, and that first `if` statement will always be true as long as you are not logged in

Comment: @JaromandaX you mean like this? http://collabedit.com/yw6kx

Comment: no idea what that link does, so not going there

Comment: @JaromandaX it's shareing code website i shared my code there.

Comment: yeah, well, I still won't go there - posted an answer - test it - if it works, accept it :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic causes an infinite redirection to `/login`

try the following logic - I think it's right

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  var requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  if (to.path != '/login' && !store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
    next({
      name: 'login'
    });
  } else if (to.path == '/login' && store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
    next({
      name: 'home'
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

---

As a bonus, here's what I mean by Promise constructor anti-pattern

axios returns a promise ... no need to wrap it in a new Promise constructor

So, for example, your login function should be written

```
login({commit}, user){
    commit('auth_request');
    return axios({url: '/api/auth/login', data: user, method: 'POST' })
    .then(resp => {
        console.log('login data', resp);
        const token = resp.data.token;
        const type = resp.data.token_type;
        const user = resp.data.user;
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        localStorage.setItem('token_type', type);
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =  'Bearer ' + token;
        commit('auth_success', token, type, user);
        return resp;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        commit('auth_error');
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        throw err;
    });
}
```

Comment: that prevent the exceeded error but one i click on links such as login or logout i get `uncaught (in promise)` error. could it be related to this beforeeach or that's something else?  `PS` in case you want to see i made screen recording of the error  https://www.loom.com/share/81807ff673e94b688b90d9c97c01c083

Comment: *ncaught (in promise) error* - surely it says more than that - if not, use a browser that gives meaningful errors

Comment: I think you already watch the video i shared all i'm getting is `Uncaught (in promise) undefined`

Comment: clearly something in your promise code is attempting to use a property of something that is `undefined` - have you tried debugging this new problem yourself?

Comment: it was duplicated redirect after login, one in my beforeeach and one in my login function. Thanks for the help appreciate it.

Comment: @mafortis - I've added bonus code to help you remove a common Promise anti-pattern

Comment: Thanks for that, still i get `Uncaught (in promise) undefined` and no return to next page :/ canfused by this vuejs

Comment: you must still be doing something wrong with something in your code - something is undefined, and you aren't expecting it to be undefined - debug it with console.logs